# is it possible to override url in textview?

Tags: android, url, textview, overriding

In a webview it is possible to override urls via shouldOverrideUrlLoading  method. That is if you have a url to maps.google.com , you can override that link and open it via maps application.

So just like webview, is there any tools for textview for url overriding ?

Any suggestions welcome.